# Can I use Bachelor and Master in German?

Tags: word-usage

I found a topic about that:
[How to discuss your graduation?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-discuss-your-graduation)

However, I can not find true options for Bachelor and Master.

I saw using "Grund- und Hauptstudium" for undergraduation and graduation.

I want to say:

> I had to focus on English at the Bachelor and Master.
>   Ich musste mich auf Englisch in ---- und ---- konzentrieren.

Comment: Somewhat tangential to the question: Please note that in contexts where "Grund- und Hauptstudium" are used (normally, the pre-Bologna ~5-year-degrees), graduation usually takes place at the *end* of the Hauptstudium. So, technically, students remain "undergraduate" all the way through their "Grund- und Hauptstudium". Post-Bologna, while Bachelor and Master are now common terms, terms such as "undergraduate" and "graduate" (or German equivalents thereof) are still not common in German, though (because the concept did not exist before).

Comment: BTW, the word order _ich musste mich im Bachelor und Master auf Englisch konzentrieren_ is probably more appropriate (though it depends on what you want to emphasize: that it was English you had to focus on, or that it was during the Bachelor/Master when you had to focus on it).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the [Bologna process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process), many German higher education qualifications have been reformed from diplomas or similar to Bachelor and Master. Therefore, those terms are known in Germany as well.

Regarding your example, in most cases "Bachelor" and "Master" are used to refer to the degrees, not the period of study. For the latter, you might want to use "Bachelorstudium" or "Masterstudium", respectively.

Comment: Bachelorstudium or Bachelor-Studium?

Comment: As far as i am concerned, like that;
"Ich musste mich auf Englisch im Bachelorstudium und Masterstudium konzentrieren."
oder
"Ich musste mich auf Englisch im Bachelor- und Masterstudium konzentrieren."

Comment: @Iris duden.de [lists "Bachelorstudium"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bachelorstudium), and I'd agree. The term is imho common enough to ommit marking the components with a hyphen.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck, thank you for the reference. In another answer here (http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-discuss-your-graduation) they use both.